# C++ is_trivially_copyable check

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memcpy, type-traits, memcmp

How to check whether or not C++ type is trivially copyable? I have a class, which uses memcpy and memcmp functions with specified template type T and I would like to fire assert for types, that are not safe to copy with memcpy. Is there any way to do that (with existing standard)?

Comment: You may be able to use the `is_pod` type trait. What is your definition of "safe to copy with `memcpy`"? If an object has a pointer data member that points to an owned dynamically allocated object, is that "safe to copy with `memcpy`"?

Comment: @James: The definition is, trivial copy constructor- that is, the type does not have a user-defined copy constructor, nor any base classes or data members with such.

Comment: The definition from standard "A trivially copyable class is a class that: 
- has no non-trivial copy constructors (12.8), 
- has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), 
- has a trivial destructor (12.4)."

Comment: @DeadMG, @axe: I suspect @James knows both those definitions, but he still raises a very good question - is that *really* the correct thing to check for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make it impossible for someone to use my class with types, that have non-trivial copy-constructor.

Comment: This is a terrible thing to do, as far as I'm concerned- but that doesn't mean that the question isn't valid.

Comment: Yes, I know what a trivially copyable class is; my question was more along the lines of:  what are you trying to accomplish and are you sure that checking whether a type is trivially copyable is really what you want to do?

Comment: @DeadMG: You wrote: _This is a terrible thing to do, as far as I'm concerned_. Why is that terrible thing? Terrible would be to allow user to crash the program by using class with inappropriate types.

Comment: @James McNellis: There is template class, which has to work ONLY with trivially copyable types by it's definition. That's what specification  says. Of course there are reasons for that.

Comment: @axe: Because, I mean, what could you possibly be doing that could require such a thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, not possible in C++98/C++03.  Things like this are why `<type_traits>` was added to C++0x.  Some of the features from `<type_traits>` can be implemented in C++03, often using the SFINAE principle, but several, including `std::is_trivially_copyable<T>`, will simply require built-in compiler support.

Comment: Yes, that was my impression too. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are type traits available for this in boost.

However, you're wasting your time- memcpying a type is not going to be faster than what your optimizer will produce with a copy constructor if the type *is* trivially copyable. Just use the copy constructor.

Comment: Which type traits? is_pod is not exactly what I'm looking for, as Maxim pointed it is nearly the same.

Comment: _However, you're wasting your time- memcpying a type is not going to be faster than what your optimizer will produce with a copy constructor if the type is trivially copyable. Just use the copy constructor._ I'ts not for the performance, I just don't want my class to work for types with non-trivial copy constructor. I could specialize it for all integral types, however then it will not work for POD's.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing is [boost::is_pod<>](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pod.html).